# How do browsers handle URLs with a fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I've run into a situation where I would like to be sure about how do browsers handle URIs that include a fragment identifier, such as `Products#A`. Imagine my website has two pages: `Products` and `FAQs`. Then, inside each I want to use # to navigate to specific HTML elements. So:

1. What is the difference between `href="Products#A"` and `href="#A"` if I'm already in page `Products`?
2. And if I'm in page `FAQs`?
3. Does placing an URL like in `href="Products#A"` always triggers a server call or does the browser know that it is already on page `Products` and it does not make a server call?
4. What is I add a `/` (like `href="/products#A"`)? Does this force a server call?
5. Is this standard for all browsers?

I've run a few tests but I'm missing some theory here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link, fragment excepted, resolves to the same URL as the current page, then it will navigate around the current page.

If it resolves to a different page, then it will load a new page.

It doesn't matter how the relative (or absolute) URL is actually expressed, only what it resolves to.

Comment: When you say that if it resolves to the same  URL as the current page it will navigate to the current page you mean that it will not make a server call, right? If so, why is it that (at least in my test) when I don't have internet connection it doesn't work? I thought it would just navigate to the # in that page that was already loaded...that's why this question seems simple but I don't think it is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, I am doing these with my own experience.

1. **What is the difference between `href="Products#A"` and `href="#A"` if I'm already in page `Products`?**

   *Nothing. Just for safety, and if you are in a different page, and the content is rendered using the same partial (or the same source), this might help.*
2. **And if I'm in page `FAQs`?**

   *It navigates normally to `Products` and finds the element with `id="A"` and scrolls to there.*
3. **Does placing an URL like in `href="Products#A"` always triggers a server call or does the browser know that it is already on page `Products` and it does not make a server call?**

   *That's a client call, no server calls are made for URL fragments.*
4. **Is this standard for all browsers?**

   *I believe so.*

Comment: I've just added question number 4. Does it force a server call?

Comment: @PauloJaneiro It forces a server call, if the link expired in the cache and / or if the page is not `Products`. Did this clear?

Comment: Ok, but like I said in my comment to Quentin, you can see at www.nutriner.com that when you navigate further the home page and then use the links in the menu to navigate to other virtual pages (using #) without internet connection they don't show. They should (as you already loaded main.html)!

Comment: @PauloJaneiro They are loaded using AJAX buddy.

Comment: Praveen, I appreciate your support, but in fact they aren't. I made them using Phoenixframework on server side and zero client-side framework/Ajax. Everything is pure CSS tricks and a simple router I made. And that's why I also surprised with this issue because it was supposed to be really simple as that website has only two pages: 'index' and 'main' and writing the URL differently (main.html# vs #) is leading to different results. Probably the way I'm manipulating 'window.location.hash' but it is also strange. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Yes :) and now, the first link I click after coming  from `index` makes a server call and further clicks don't (render immediately).  I just can't understand that first click call when you're already at the `main` page...